# How to order rows when custom model is made from GUI in Odoo v 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I have made a custom model using GUI. This model contains a field named `sequence`.

I want to order my rows by this field.

This same this has been done for `res.company` model and i want the same.

So, for companies

`_order = 'sequence, name'` is written in model.

and `widget='handle'` is used in tree view that orders various companies just by drag and drop.

So, i added this widget attribute in my tree view, but i don't know where to use `_order='sequence'`(the field I created in my model) because i don't have code for that model.

Is there a way that i can do i from GUI itself or I need to create that model from code??

Comment: By GUI you mean the Odoo Studio?

Comment: No, the odoo web client GUI. Using odoo from my browser